# Vertical middle alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment

```css
#page-header {
    display: table;
    font-size: 26px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#page-header div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.fontHelvetica {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS",Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-header">
  <div class="fontHelvetica">Social<span class="fontLightMaroon">Network</span></div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload"></div>
 </div>
```

I want to align the button in middle with the text "SocialNetwork". The font size may change, accordingly the button should align in middle. 
I am using the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `<input>` doesn't receive the the inherit font size/line height correctly, and it's depending on the browser and OS. What you can do is set the large font on the "SocialNetwork" only, i.e.

```
#page-header {font-size: 26px;} /*remove this*/
.fontHelvetica {font-size:26px;} /*add this*/
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/f43ut27s/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `div` wrapper of the `input` button and give the `input` the style as below. The button will remain vertically aligned to the middle no matter the `font-size`.

```css
#page-header {
  display: table;
  font-size: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#page-header div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#page-header input {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: -5px 0 0 5px;
}
.fontHelvetica {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-header">
  <div class="fontHelvetica">Social<span class="fontLightMaroon">Network</span></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" />
</div>
```

Example with a *different* `font-size`:

```css
#page-header {
  display: table;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#page-header div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#page-header input {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: -5px 0 0 5px;
}
.fontHelvetica {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-header">
  <div class="fontHelvetica">Social<span class="fontLightMaroon">Network</span>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with display: table-cell, it does not allow for linebreak after the first div.

Ive created a fiddle here that breaks the line, makes the button be perceived as "text" block (display: inline-block), and aligned it to center with

```
text-align: center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gn4jqLea/

Answer (score 0):

I have insert css property display:inline-block;font-size:2em; in fontHelvetica class

```css
#page-header {
    display: table;
    font-size: 26px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#page-header div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.fontHelvetica {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS",Helvetica,sans-serif;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-header">
  <div class="fontHelvetica">Social<span class="fontLightMaroon">Network</span></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" />
</div>
```